# how to copy a part of String[] in each index to another?

Tags: java

Consider

```
String[] string1={"abc\n123","def\n456","ghi\n789"};
```

Now how to make an array (say string2) from string1 having content like this

```
string2= {"abc","def","ghi"};
```

Is this possible?
If yes, then how?

Comment: Yes it's possible, using regex, look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> string2 = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String string : string1){
     string2.add(string.split("\n")[0]);
}
```

Did not actually run my code, but it will at least give you the idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] string1={"abc\n123","def\n456","ghi\n789"};
String[] string2 = new String[3];
int i=0;
for (String s : string1){
    String s2 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('\n'));
    string2[i] = s2;
    i++;
}
for (String string : string2) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
String[] string1={"abc\n123","def\n456","ghi\n789"};

    String[] str = new String[string1.length];
    for(int i=0;i<string1.length;i++){
        String s1 = string1[i].split("\n")[0]; 
        str[i] = s1;            
    }

    for(int i=0;i<string1.length;i++){
        System.out.println(str[i]);
    }
```

comment about result